# how to use all to filter list above threshold

Tags: python

```
x=[255, 255, 255, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 255, 255, 255]
y=all([i for i in x if i>260])
y1 = all([i for i in x if i>220])
y2 = all([True for i in x if i>260])
y3 = all([True for i in x if i>220])
y1==y2==y3==y #gives True
```

How does `all` handle empty lists, and how can I use to filter items above 220.
the only thing working for me now is

```
y=len([i for i in x if i>220])== len(x)
```

what I want to know if all list is above certain number i.e 220

Comment: Are you just trying to count how many elements in a list meet a certain condition?

Comment: @NateDellinger no I want to to know if all elements in the list are above certain threshold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this:

```
all([i > 220 for i in x])
```

`all` for an empty list should be `True`, because all of its elements - all 0 of them - are truthy

Edit: if it's desired to rule out the trivial case where `x` is empty, then as suggested in the comments just add an additional check for that, such as `len(X) > 0`

Comment: this fills list True,False and the does `and` between elements right?

Comment: If you wanted to make sure there is at least one element in the list above your threshold (220, 260), you could add a check that makes sure the list isn't empty: `all([i > 220 for i in x]) and len(x) > 0`

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge I believe he should add that to make answer complete and error proof

Comment: Thanks, I've added this to the answer

Answer (score 2):

There are some small tweaks required to make your list comprehensions work. For instance, you don't handle the case in which the value in the list is not greater than *x*. For example, let's assume our list is:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

If we use the code snipped from your question:

```
>>> [True for i in x if i > 3]
[True, True, True]
```

The result is probably not exactly what you expected. Therefore, **calling `all()` on that list will always evaluate to `True`.** One small tweak, however (note the addition of the `else` statement):

```
>>> [True if i > 3 else False for i in x]
[False, False, False, True, True, True]
```

This is the desired output. Now you can also apply `all()` to the output list.

```
>>> y1 = [True if i > 3 else False for i in x]
>>> all(y1)
False
```

And if we want to know whether all values are greater than 0, we expect `all()` to return `True` in the following case:

```
>>> y2 = [True if i > 0 else False for i in x]
>>> all(y2)
True
```

To answer your question about how `all()` handles empty lists:

```
>>> all([])
True
```

Depending on the structure of your code and the desired output you may want to have an edge case statement that handles empty lists. Hopefully this is enough input for you to adapt it to your problem statement.

---

**Making the code more compact:** As very kindly pointed out in the comments, the code above is a bit "wordy" to make a point and for the sake of the explanation. When writing list comprehensions and condition statements in Python (and perhaps other programming languages), you can actually shorten the list comprehension and condition statement:

```
>>> y1 = [i > 3 for i in x]
>>> y1
[False, False, False, True, True, True]
>>> all(y1)
False
```

`i > 3` in the list comprehension will turn into `True` or `False` and therefore yield the same result as writing `True if i > 3 else False`.

---

Finally, **if you want to know if all elements meet the threshold and there is *at least one* element in the list:**

```
>>> y1 = [i > 3 for i in x]
>>> y1
[False, False, False, True, True, True]
>>> all(y1) and y1
[]  # this will evaluate to False if you use it in a condition statement
```

Alternatively you can also convert it to a boolean:

```
>>> bool(all(y1) and y1)
False
```

Which does the right thing for empty lists as well:

```
>>> bool(all([]) and [])
False
```

Comment: This is a good explanation but I feel it's incomplete without pointing out that you would (or should) never use an expression like `True if i > 3 else False` in real code - because it's identical to the expression `i > 3`

Comment: Yes, you're right of course. I'll edit my answer shortly. My answer was wordy for the sake of the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `True for i in x if i>260`, do `i>260 for i in x`

`i>260` will result in a boolean: True, or False for each element.